# Getting files and folders excluding files from sub-folders from s3 in .Net

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

I know there are only objects in s3. But lets just go with a convention of files/folders for better explaination.
I want to get the files/folders list from a specific folder on s3 non recursively. By non-recursive I mean, I want to exclude all the files/folders laying into the sub-directories. I only want to fetch the direct descendants of a specific folder.

I tried calling s3 by setting a delimiter = "/". But it will only fetch direct files.:

```
ListObjectsRequest listRequest = new ListObjectsRequest
{
  BucketName = info.BucketName,
  Prefix = path,
  Delimiter = "/"
};
ListObjectsResponse listResponse = s3.ListObjects(listRequest);
```

Here, I was able to get direct files. But is there any way to get direct folders?

Comment: You will get a list of everything inside that prefix. As far as i know there is no way around that. The folders will all end with a '/' so you can filter them out in your code.

Comment: Thanks Ninad. For now I have applied filter on all the files and folders fetch. I guess we will have wait till amazon provides us with an option to optimize it